# checkbox updated via jQuery not checked in form submission, but is on screen

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have no idea how this is not working correctly. This is in a script tag on a wordpress page if that matter, there is a ton of other JS dynamically changing the page around which works fine, including the "disabled" and "checked" which visually appear the right way on the screen, but when i submit my form its not picking up that the box is checked.

```
        jQuery('#mec_fes_categories94').prop("disabled", true);
        jQuery('#mec_fes_categories94').prop("checked", true);
```

If i disabled this code and manually use the checkbox it works fine.

Comment: have you tried swapping the lines and see if that works, so you check it before you disable it?

Comment: same result, works on screen but not picking up in form submission

Answer (score 1):

After some digging, it seems that my form uses POST submission and when you use the disabled property, you lose the value. WTF!!!!!

From another post:
You could use disabled="disabled" but at this point checkbox's value will not appear into POST values. One of the strategy is to add an hidden field holding checkbox's value within the same form and read value back from that field